# Android mouse input via uinput is being accelerated

Tags: android, linux, input

I'm using a `uinput` to control an Android phone from my PCs mouse and keyboard.

The problem I'm having is that I can't get the cursor position to match up to what's being sent from the PC as Android is accelerating/smoothing them (which is an absolute requirement for this project).

I've tried relative mouse movements using `EV_REL`. I've also tried absolute positioning using `EV_ABS` and `BTN_TOUCH` to simulate a touchscreen but, strangely, this too has acceleration.

Is there a way of either disabling acceleration or sending absolute positioned click events?

Comment: can you give details on how you use uinput?

Comment: I would set a monitor on input events received on your uinput event node. This way to can see the exact parameters involved and it's easy to reproduce them.